# Is there any way to get the address of a `struct` in Rust?

Tags: struct, rust

I have tried using raw pointer casts, like `my_struct as *const usize`, but this results in a `non-scalar cast` error. Raw pointers seem to work fine when finding the address of primitives, but not custom `struct`s.

Answer (score 46, accepted):

You need to use the `&` operator to get the address of any variable, so you need to write `&my_struct as *const _` (where `_` can be a literal `_`, or the type of the value behind the pointer).

Comment: Right. This is example of it: https://gist.github.com/Denys-Bushulyak/b75d2e124532bf5b4c1b7d70ec8214ae

Comment: Side note: for mutable raw pointer, the casting is similar `&mut my_struct as * mut  _`

Answer (score 7):

See the [`std::ptr::addr_of`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/macro.addr_of.html) macro. This is especially useful when taking a reference (as suggested in the accepted answer) is not possible due to memory alignment issues.

Here is the example given in the docs on `std::ptr::addr_of`:

```rust
use std::ptr;

#[repr(packed)]
struct Packed {
    f1: u8,
    f2: u16,
}

let packed = Packed { f1: 1, f2: 2 };
// `&packed.f2` would create an unaligned reference, and thus be Undefined Behavior!
let raw_f2 = ptr::addr_of!(packed.f2);
assert_eq!(unsafe { raw_f2.read_unaligned() }, 2);
```