# Convert C struct to raw pointer in Rust

Tags: winapi, rust

I'm playing around with windows.rs and I would like to create a network link using NetUseAdd function from "Win32_NetworkManagement_NetManagement". I faced an issue and I would like to know how can I convert the c struct to raw pointer for useinfo?

```
unsafe {
    let mut parm_err: Option<*mut u32> = None;
    let remote = conver_pwstr("//WIN-HDOB90189BJ/Users/test/Desktop/share//");
    let password = conver_pwstr("test");
    let username = conver_pwstr("test");
    let mut useifo: USE_INFO_2 = USE_INFO_2::default();
    useifo.ui2_local = remote; 
    useifo.ui2_username = username;
    useifo.ui2_password = password;

    let levelflags: u32 = 2;

    NetUseAdd(None, levelflags, useifo, parm_err);
}
```

NetUseAdd(None, levelflags, useifo, parm_err);

Error: expected *-ptr, found struct `windows::Win32::NetworkManagement::NetManagement::USE_INFO_2`

Comment: Pass `&useifo`? Possibly `&useifo as *const _`? See [Is there any way to get the address of a `struct` in Rust?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35882994/364696)

Comment: casting `&windows::Win32::NetworkManagement::NetManagement::USE_INFO_2` as `*const u8` is invalid

Comment: You'll need to cast twice: `&useifo as *const USE_INFO_2 as *const u8`.